# Storing Google Places ID and passing to UIView

Tags: ios, swift, google-places-api, gmsautocomplete

I am having some issues storing place details from *Google Places*. I can build the app fine but then crashes when I select a place from the `GMSAutocompleteViewController`... 
"Could not cast value of type 'GMSPlace' (0x10075bec8) to 'NSString' (0x1afec1398)."

I would like to save the selected place data and then send that data to be displayed in a UIView and UITableView. Not sure what I am doing wrong...

```
    // MARK: GOOGLE AUTO COMPLETE DELEGATE

    func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {

        // Do something with the selected place.
        // A hotel in Saigon with an attribution.
//        let placeID = "ChIJV4k8_9UodTERU5KXbkYpSYs"
        let placeID = GMSPlace.self

        placesClient.lookUpPlaceID((placeID as AnyObject) as! String, callback: { (place, error) -> Void in
            if let error = error {
                print("lookup place id query error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }

            guard let place = place else {
                print("No place details for \(placeID)")
                return
            }

            print("Place name \(place.name)")
            print("Place address \(place.formattedAddress)")
            print("Place placeID \(place.placeID)")
            print("Place attributions \(place.attributions)")
        })

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        setupConfirmationPopUp()

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code (`GMSPlace.self`) is creating a reference to the `GMSPlace` type itself, not a particular instance. The delegate method will provide back the instance of the `GMSPlace` that the view controller was able to autocomplete to. Using this instance you can get the place ID from the property called [`placeID`](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/reference/interface_g_m_s_place.html#a126c0feb110b9687c45dfb05ceb2731b).

Try.

```
func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {

    // Do something with the selected place.
    // A hotel in Saigon with an attribution.
    // let placeID = "ChIJV4k8_9UodTERU5KXbkYpSYs"
    let placeID = place.placeID

    placesClient.lookUpPlaceID(placeID, callback: { (place, error) -> Void in
        if let error = error {
            print("lookup place id query error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        guard let place = place else {
            print("No place details for \(placeID)")
            return
        }

        print("Place name \(place.name)")
        print("Place address \(place.formattedAddress)")
        print("Place placeID \(place.placeID)")
        print("Place attributions \(place.attributions)")
    })

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    setupConfirmationPopUp()

}
```

Comment: Had to remove the casting of the placeID as! String but that worked, thanks!

Comment: I wasn't sure if that would still be needed as `placeID` comes back as an `NSString`. Fixed in an edit.